# Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing

Tags: nginx

I have an IIS website that initiates a websocket connection between the browser and the server.  The URL looks something like this:  `http://stream.mydomain.com/h264.html?serverid=192.168.1.52`.  Obviously, this connection cannot be made externally, so I'm trying to use NGinx to allow that.  I have a subdomain called `streams.mydomain.com` and I'm attempting to reroute based on the path, so my new URL would look like `http://stream.mydomain.com/h264.html?serverid=streams.mydomain.com/101`.  I've tried a couple routes, including `proxy_pass` which results in an unexpected response.  Right now I'm trying `return` but I keep having header issues.  Specifically, it's saying a header doesn't exist even though I'm explicitly including it and it shows up in the request in Chrome.

Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen      *;
    server_name streams.mydomain.net;
    location /101/ {
        add_header  'Connection'    'Upgrade';
        add_header  'Upgrade'       websocket;
        return      101             $scheme://192.168.1.52;
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing
```

And here is a screenshot of the request in Chrome debug tools, which appear to me to show the "missing" header:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of a working request using the local IP on the internal network (no NGinx):

[image]

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Comment: Posted answer. Sorry I forgot to get back earlier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't accomplish exactly what I wanted with the routes, but this is the solution I had to go with:

```
http {
    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name server101.domain.com;
        location / {
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Connection  "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
            proxy_pass          $scheme://10.1.5.98:80;
        }
    }
}
```

I would still like to figure out how to do servers.domain.com/101 some day.